# Effect of frequency resolution on the frequency spectrum of impulse force delivered by an electromagnetic shaker

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, vibration

this is a part of my parameter study for the experiment (a vibration analysis with a force impulse input). This specific part studies the frequency resolution effect on the spectrum. The input (i.e.: impulse force)
[image]

My main question is: why increasing frequency resolution (or frequency bin) would lead to the disappearances of sudden peaks at 50 and 150 Hz?

Note that the original input signal is the same, the **only** thing changed is the number of FFT lines (also known as spectral lines) and via that the frequency resolution.

Edit: Upload for measurement set-up
[image]

Edit 2: Sampled point format
[image]

Sampled point format, from 0 to 170 Hz (zoom in)
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118937/discussion-on-question-by-comradeh-effect-of-frequency-resolution-on-the-frequen).